# how to create virtual directory to my silverlight application in Local IIS

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I developed Silverlight Project With Wcf and linq to sql.

Now I Created Virtual Directory to My Project And I Executed My Project then i got Error like This:

```
Error 1 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'; beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. `

E:\vijay\FirstGuardianSecure\FirstGuardian.Web\Web.config
```

Please Give me idea how to solve my problem.

Comment: Check the below link: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on your virtual directory >>menu property >> and than one dialog get apper in that dilog box click create web application...

As you see in below image "**Application name:**" there is button close to it **Remove**
 with may be in your case "**Create**"

[image]

You solution : [How to: Create and Configure Virtual Directories in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This is how you do it in IIS 6. I guess, because Vijay is using Silverlight and WCF, he may be using IIS 7 or above. Please see my answer for IIS 7+

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using IIS 7 or above:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. In the Connections pane, expand the Sites node.
3. Right-click the site for which you want to create an application, and click Add Application.
4. In the Alias text box, type a value for the application URL, such as marketing. This value is used to access the application in a URL.
5. Click Select if you want to select a different application pool than the one listed in the Application pool box. In the Select Application Pool dialog box, select an application pool from the Application pool list and then click OK.
6. In the Physical path text box, type the physical path of the application's folder, or click the browse button (...) to navigate the file system to find the folder.
7. Optionally, click Connect as to specify credentials that have permission to access the physical path. If you do not use specific credentials, select the Application user (pass-thru authentication) option on the Connect As dialog box.
8. Optionally, click Test Settings to verify the settings that you specified for the application.
9. Click OK.

Here is the Microsoft technet article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(v=ws.10).aspx